# Hybris Custom WSDTO on hybris product data

Tags: customization, sap-commerce-cloud

Hi I had created eProductForm bean in the commerecefacades-beans.xml I added custom attribute of ProductData.

```
<bean class="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.data.ProductData">
<property name="eProductForm" type="String"/>    
</bean>
```

then in commercewebservice-beans.xml, I added the custom attribute of ProductWsDTO

```
<bean class="de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.product.ProductWsDTO">
<property name="eProductForm" type="String"/></bean>
```

from SearchResultProductPopulator populated productdata of eProductForm from my search result.

```
target.setEProductForm(this.<String> getValue(source, "E_PRODUCT_FORM"));
```

PFB
dto mapping

```
<bean parent="fieldSetLevelMapping" id="productWsDTOFieldSetLevelMapping">
 <property name="dtoClass"   value="de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.product.ProductWsDTO"/>
<property name="levelMapping">
<map>
<entry key="BASIC"
      value="purchasable,stock,name,baseProduct,availableForPickup,code,url,price"/>
<entry key="DEFAULT"
      value="summary,averageRating,purchasable,stock(DEFAULT),description,variantMatrix(DEFAULT),name,baseOptions(DEFAULT),baseProduct,availableForPickup,variantOptions(DEFAULT),code,url,price(DEFAULT),numberOfReviews,manufacturer,categories(BASIC),priceRange,multidimensional,configuratorType,configurable,tags"/>
<entry key="FULL"
      value="summary,productReferences(FULL),classifications(FULL),averageRating,purchasable,volumePrices(FULL),variantType,stock(FULL),description,variantMatrix(FULL),name,baseOptions(FULL),baseProduct,availableForPickup,variantOptions(FULL),reviews(FULL),code,url,price(FULL),numberOfReviews,manufacturer,volumePricesFlag,futureStocks(FULL),images(FULL),categories(FULL),potentialPromotions(FULL),priceRange,multidimensional,configuratorType,configurable,tags,eProductForm,ePickledGroup"/>
</map>
</property>
</bean>
```

Below is the code I am calling Mapper.. While I debugged my code sourceresult is having product data of that custom attreibute. But I am not getting the eproductform in the WSDTO response.

```
final ProductSearchPageData<SearchStateData, ProductData> sourceResult = searchProducts(query, currentPage, pageSize, sort);
    if (sourceResult instanceof ProductCategorySearchPageData)
    {
        return getDataMapper().map(sourceResult, ProductCategorySearchPageWsDTO.class, fields);
    }
```

But in logs I see:

> [EL Warning]: 2019-02-20 18:31:27.341--Ignoring attribute
>   [eProductForm] on class
>   [de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.product.ProductWsDTO]
>   as no Property was generated for it.

Comment: Can you see the new attribute(eProductForm) if you open the class(i.e de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.product.ProductWsDTO) ?
If no, are you sure you performed an 'ant clean all' after you updated the commercewebservice-beans.xml ?

Comment: Can you ensure that you are calling the mapper in FULL mode as you have added the attribute only for FULL mode. Also, please ensure that the attribute eProductForm has a non null value.

Answer (score 2):

As @Farrukh Chishti commented, the URL that you used probably used the DEFAULT level, which doesn't contain the attribute you added. For testing purposes, you can try to add the attribute to BASIC, DEFAULT, and FULL.

In the URL, you can specify the level, something like this:

> https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/custom_site/stores?&fields=FULL

Comment: thanks all.. its patch issue :( . issue got resolved

Comment: @ManigandanKarthick That's good to hear. Maybe you can post your answer as something like "It was an issue in Hybris 6.6.0.1" and it was fixed when I upgraded to "Hybris 6.6.0.5.